# using the chrome console to select out data

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking to pull out all of the companies from this page (https://angel.co/finder#AL_claimed=true&AL_LocationTag=1849&render_tags=1) in plain text. I saw someone use the Chrome Developer Tools console to do this and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction?

TLDR; How do I use Chrome console to select and pull out some data from a URL?

Answer (score 2):

Note: since [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is available on this page, I'll just go ahead and use it.

First of all, we need to select elements that we want, e.g. names of the companies. These are being kept on the list with ID `startups_content`, inside elements with class `items` in a field with class `name`. Therefore, selector for these can look like this:

```
$('#startups_content .items .name a')
```

As a result, we will get bunch of HTMLElements. Since we want a plain text we need to extract it from these HTMLElements by doing:

```
.map(function(idx, item){ return $(item).text(); }).toArray()
```

Which gives us an array of company names. However, lets make a single plain text list out of it:

```
.join('\n')
```

Connecting all the steps above we get:

```
$('#startups_content .items .name a').map(function(idx, item){ return $(item).text(); }).toArray().join('\n');
```

which should be executed in the DevTools console.

If you need some other data, e.g. company URLs, just follow the same steps as described above doing appropriate changes.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you so much. I went ahead and also pulled out the joined date and the "resume" (description".  Now I have gotten all of the data - now want to use regex to get it into CSV format so I can enter it into the DB. Any tips on where to start with that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ended up with, but if with 3 files (name,description,date) then just fire up excel (or google spreadsheets), copy data from each file and paste it to different columns in your spreadsheet, then just do a CSV export.